# Retriving the database values and php textbox values

Tags: php, mysql

i have one doubt on retriving the value from database as well as from textbox in php.

i have created table like this,

```
id    blockid   flatno
1       1A        100
2       1B        200
3       2A        100
4       2B        200
```

if i try to insert again `flatno` as `100` in the same block it has to show one error message like this `flatno` is already exists in the `blockid 1A` how to do this.. please help me..

Comment: you can give unique in table design other wise you can check already exist or not using php code(using ajax is more efficient)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your table not add Unique index, so please add the Unique index  and insert Your Data
and check database error
or by code
$

```
query = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM tablename WHERE flatno=".$flatno." AND blockid=".$blockid);
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($result > 0){
  echo " The Details already exists"; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
WHERE flatno=@flatno
AND blockid=@blockid
```

if the above query returns something, show an error message.

```
echo "Flat No. already exists in this block";
```

Comment: it's not Selection problem  it is inserting problem

Comment: @krish: Read the question carefully. OP **wants** to show an error message if same `flatno` is entered.

Comment: @ok that's my mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT *  FROM tablename WHERE flatno=".$flatno." AND blockid=".$blockid);
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($result > 0){
  echo "already exists"; 
 }
else{
      //insert query
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add unique index constraint to the table for block_no and flatno columns.  that way there will not be any duplicate combination of block_no and flatno and mysql throws error as soon as you try to insert a duplicate of this.

Alter table <tablename> add constraint UQ_FLATNO unique (block_no,flatno);

once this unique constraint is added then if you try to insert a duplicate flatno combination then the sql will throw a error.

In your query execution check can be done like this:
if (mysql_errno() == 1062) {
    echo 'duplicate key';
}
```